# Rails partial - local variable name from variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have some code to render a partial, which includes:

```
:locals => {:feature => y}
```

This works fine, but I would like to be able to use a variable in place of `:feature` - I have tried the following:

```
:locals => {type.singularize => y}
```

but to no avail. What is the correct syntax to replace `:feature` with a local variable?

Comment: weird... even `type.singularize.to_sym`?

Comment: Maybe `type.singularize.to_sym`?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Thanks - <code>type.singularize.to_sym</code> has done the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone else comes across this, I was able to resolve it using the code in the comments from apneadiving and MurifoX:

```
:locals => {type.singularize.to_sym => y}
```